# Counting towards maximum hosts in an enterprise WiFi network

Tags: wifi, networking

If you have an enterprise WiFi network of about 100 APs where LWAPP/CAPWAP is used and all APs and controllers are in the same management VLAN.  If you're counting hosts in the broadcast domain to find out if you should segment your network, only the APs, controllers, and other hosts in the management VLAN count correct? Not the clients that connect to the APs?

Clients are in a different VLAN than the APs, decided by the SSID, so broadcasts from clients don't reach other APs, they only reach other clients. However, I was wondering if the clients should count anyway since they generate traffic on the AP.

Answer (score 1):

When you count hosts on a subnet, you generally do this to get a handle on broadcast traffic. Since none of the client broadcasts are on that subnet, I wouldn't worry about it. They are all tunneled back to the controller which then puts them out on the client VLAN